# URI::InvalidURIError while i am testing with rspec+capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am testing with RSpec+capybara, but i've got the error:

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title', :text => "YourPos | About")
   expected  #has_selector?("title", {:text=>"YourPos | About"}) to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And my static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do 

  describe "About page" do

    it "should have the title 'About' " do
        visit '/static_pages/about'
        page.should have_selector('title', :text => "YourPos | About")
    end
  end

end
```

And my app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YourPos | About</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Find me in app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Wish someone will help me, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
visit 'static_pages/about'
```

to

```
visit '/static_pages/about'
```

Comment: I did that, but i got an another error. I change the question's details, and what's the problem now?

Comment: It's telling you that the text you are looking for is not on the page that is returned.  What happens when you visit the page normally?

Comment: try page.should have_content 'YourPos | About'

Comment: OK, then it looks like there is a problem with your app because the code above should be working.  Are you running Spork or anything like that?

Comment: Spork? No, i don't know that kind of things